# Truncate a file inside Android filesystem

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, shell, busybox

I have a large (1.3GB) binary file on internal/emulated storage of an Android device running KitKat (4.4.2, API 19); I want to truncate this file to a slightly smaller size (1.2GB), without copying/transferring it all over again.

Device is rooted, and I have adb + shell access.

On Linux I could have just run `truncate --size=1.2G path/to/file`; however the shell pre-installed on the device is BusyBox `v1.21.0-jb bionic`, which doesn't seem to contain a built-in `truncate` command. Based on [BusyBox changelogs](https://busybox.net/), `truncate` was only added in 1.24.0.

What are my options?

- Device storage has only ~400MB left, so making a `dd`-style copy of required size (and then deleting the original) is not an option.
- Could not find an alternative command that would behave in this way (remove trailing content from file / shrink it, in-place).
- Tried copying and running the `truncate` binary from another device (Android 8.0); however it wasn't compatible (gave an error `CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: empty/missing DT_HASH in "./truncate" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)`) (FWIW in the end, found that the binary was actually a `toybox` multi-call binary). All other devices at my disposal don't seem to contain `truncate` command.
- Tried to find a standalone `truncate` binary online - which I can install without touching the existing busybox installation - but could not find any pointers.. or at least any indication that such standalone binaries exist for Android at all
- Tried few common file browsers (device built-in file explorer com.rhmsoft.fm, ES File Explorer) but could not find a suitable action/option.

I would prefer to avoid installing a complete app/apk for this purpose alone, but would go with it if that's the only option; anyways, I'm quite doubtful if such an option would be available in APK form at all.